# Is there a tried and true way of accessing specific areas of a very large (>1 GB) binary file very fast in .NET

Tags: .net, performance, parsing, file-io, binaryfiles

Using a very large raw binary data file, I will be creating a large binary file (greater than 1 GB, usually greater than 4 GB) that contains sensor data from an arbituary number of sensors (1 to 64). The new processed file will be used by user in a GUI where they will be jumping around the file looking at different time periods or other index that may be defined. It's important that access is as smooth as possible, and I also would like to only load as much as needed (what the user sees plus maybe a bit of a buffer).

I would like to construct the processed data file such that it has an index at the beginning that is then used to jump to whatever point the person want to go.

Should I be writing this from scratch? Or are there some helper libraries that may come in use?

The reason I wouldn't just tack some indexing onto the original raw data file is that it has been created in a way that is definitely not optimal for reading individual sensors (running compression, data stored in DCT blocks, etc...).

Comment: Your question seems kind of trivial although I am sure there is more to it. It sounds like all you need is to reposition your read point in your file stream.

Comment: Maybe you need a better question subject line - your actual question seems more like: "I need a library for indexing and querying very large binary files"

Comment: Well, maybe it is trivial. You comment then becomes an answer.
I guess I am wondering if there are any gotchas to indexing very large binary files as opposed to large to small ( < 1GB) files.
The inner workings of .net system libraries are not always very clear.

Comment: I don't know about tried and true, but what I would do is open the file, then traverse and dereference the different pointers in the file until I got to the information I needed, then dump it out. Also, I'd be prone to write it in C++, but that's just me.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/files/fastbinaryfileinput.aspx

This helps me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a Memory Mapped File. In .NET 4.0 there are now wrappers:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorymappedfiles.memorymappedfile.aspx

If you need to target an earlier version you will have to p/invoke the API methods yourself:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366537.aspx